# How to use bigint type when using add_reference with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In Rails 5 and PostgreSQL.

I created this file to want to use `bigint` data type instead of `integer` by default:

```
# config/initializers/bigint_primary_keys.rb
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = 'bigserial primary key'
```

So when run create and migrate, the table id will be `bigint` type.

```
# posts table
id bigint not null
...

# users table
id bigint not null
...
```

But when using `add_reference` in the migration:

```
class ChangeA < ActiveRecord::Migration[5]
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :users
  end
end
```

The `posts` table add this field:

```
# posts table
...
user_id integer
```

Both `posts` and `users` table ids are `bigint` type, but this field does not changed.

Is there a way to set a data type to `add_reference` method?

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference

It has `type` option. That's what I want.